# Using vlookup to find any part of a larger string, in a table of possible sub strings

Tags: excel, excel-formula, ms-office, vlookup

I have a table of codes. Eg

```
1 - Big red book
2 - Tall tree
3 - Dancing tiger
```

I then have some strings as input data. I cannot control these. eg

```
The boy opened the big red book
They met at tall tree lane
Dancing with the dancing tiger
There was a tall tree in the forest
```

I need to be able to find the lookup code for each input string: eg if the input contains any value in the lookup table, return the ID

I can do this the other way round easily enough using a wildcard lookup `("*"&A1&"*")`, which would be great if I wanted to find the shorter string within the larger one... But I'm struggling with this kind of fuzzier matching: is it possible?

Comment: Could it ever contain two substrings (or more)?

Comment: I don't believe so, no, although in an ideal world I'd throw an error message out if there was: just returning the first (or last) match should be fine though

Answer (score 1):

Different ways of getting to your answer. e.g.:

[image]

Formula in `E1`:

```
=CONCAT(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&B$1:B$3&" "," "&D1&" ")),A$1:A$3,""))
```

Or a bit more Excel version friendly:

```
=INDEX(A:A,MIN(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&B$1:B$3&" "," "&D1&" ")),ROW(B$1:B$3),"")))
```

Depending on your version of Excel you should confirm through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Even, if your ID is always numeric, and as you mentioned there should always just be one substring then:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&B$1:B$3&" "," "&D1&" ")))*A$1:A$3)
```

Comment: note that the spaces are there to prevent you from matching another substring, e.g.: 'tall trees'